# FFmpeg concatenate with seeking and no re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to concatenate several .ts files while applying seek --s  to one of the input files ? I'm trying to achieve this without re-encoding.

Any ideas will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Use the concat [demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) with inpoint set.   If you skip re-encoding, accuracy may be compromised.

Comment: @Gyan thanks for your answer. In this case, could you please tell me an alternative to concat .ts files starting with a specific period but without reencoding ? I have a large ts file I need to concatenate with other parts but I don't need the first and last few seconds from the large video in the concat process. Thank you

Comment: @David You can do it without [tag:ffmpeg], the MPEG-TS format is easy to parse and there are libs like `biTStream` that make it even easier. Besides the timing related headers you'll need to know on which packet to cut the transport stream without producing errors. This can be as easy as finding a random access indicator if the stream uses them or by searching the elementary streams for IDR.

Comment: I think you would need a temp file for the seek, but copy codec should be no issue.